# Не могу правильно передать класс с ПРОБЕЛАМИ Jsoup Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, jsoup

Обычные классы работают все хорошо, а вот с пробелами ни в какую, пробовал вместо пробелов точки ставить, выдавало ошибку.
Вот как я парсил обычно

```
val element: Elements =
        document.select("div[class=container]")
        val group = element
        .select("div[class=breadcrumbs]")
        .select("span")
     .text()
    binding.textGroup.setText(group)
```

Вот что надо запарсить

```
<li class="tile swiper-slide current day_color_theoretical" style="width: 160px; margin-right: 10px;">
```

Пробовал и . и пробелы убирать и - ставил, никак

Answer (score 1):

В общем нашел официальный сайт библиотеки, там доходчиво объяснили

Правильная запись:

```
.select("li.tile.swiper-slide.current")
```

Код этой темы меняется при действиях на сайте после метода? current, поэтому до него веду и все работает